# Adding "this" to event listener?

Tags: javascript

I was creating a quiz application and decided to switch from .onclick() to .addEventListener(). In order to get that to work I had to add event handlers.

The only way I got the listeners to work was by adding the following code to the Quiz object constructor..

```
document.getElementById('guess0').addEventListener('click', this);
document.getElementById('guess1').addEventListener('click', this);
```

This works but I am not sure why. What exactly is the "this" doing in place as a function?

Entire page of code for reference:

```
function Quiz(questions) {
  this.questions = questions;
  this.score = 0;
  this.currentQuestionIndex = -1;

  document.getElementById('guess0').addEventListener('click', this);
  document.getElementById('guess1').addEventListener('click', this);

  this.displayNext();
}

Quiz.prototype.displayNext = function(){
  this.currentQuestionIndex++;

  if(this.hasEnded()){
    this.displayScore();
    this.displayProgress();
  }else{
    this.displayCurrentQuestion();
    this.displayCurrentChoices();
    this.displayProgress();
  }
};

Quiz.prototype.hasEnded = function() {
 return this.currentQuestionIndex >= this.questions.length;
};

Quiz.prototype.displayScore = function() {
  let gameOverHtml = "<h1>Game is over!</h1>";
  gameOverHtml += "<h2>Your score was: " + this.score + "!</h2>";

  let quizDiv = document.getElementById('quizDiv');
  quizDiv.innerHTML = gameOverHtml;
};

Quiz.prototype.getCurrentQuestion = function() {
  return this.questions[this.currentQuestionIndex];
};

Quiz.prototype.displayCurrentQuestion = function() {
  let currentQuestion = document.getElementById('question');
  currentQuestion.textContent = this.questions[this.currentQuestionIndex].text;
};

Quiz.prototype.displayCurrentChoices = function() {
  let choices = this.getCurrentQuestion().choices;

  for (let i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    let choiceHTML = document.getElementById('choice' + i);
    choiceHTML.innerHTML = choices[i];
  }
};

Quiz.prototype.handleEvent = function(event){
  if(event.type === 'click'){
    this.handleClick(event);  
  }
};

Quiz.prototype.handleClick = function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let choices = this.getCurrentQuestion().choices;

  if(event.target.id === "guess0"){
    this.guess(choices[0]);
  } else if(event.target.id === "guess1"){
    this.guess(choices[1]);
  }
  this.displayNext();
};

Quiz.prototype.displayProgress = function() {
  let footer = document.getElementById('quizFooter');
  if (this.hasEnded()) {
    footer.innerHTML = "You have completed the quiz!";
  } else {
    footer.innerHTML = "Question " + (this.currentQuestionIndex + 1) + " of " + this.questions.length;
  }
};

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(choice) {
  if (this.getCurrentQuestion().checkAnswer(choice)) {
    this.score++;
  }
};
```

Comment: that doesn't look right - what is `this` where you add this bizarre code

Comment: I added the entire page of code for reference.

Comment: in JavaScript this is not a mere function. You created the function constructor. When you create an object using this function constructor (object of Quiz type), then this 'this' refers that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making `Quiz` a "class" (as we normally think about classes, even if JS doesn't really have them). When you do `quiz = new Quiz(questions)`, inside the `Quiz` constructor, `this` refers to the newly created `Quiz` object. `addEventListener` can accept one of two different values for the listener parameter:

> This must be an object implementing the `EventListener` interface, or a JavaScript function.

Your `Quiz` implements the requisite interface by implementing `handleEvent` function. Thus, when you pass your newly-created quiz (as `this`) to `addEventListener`, you will get `quiz.handleEvent` invoked when the event happens.

Comment: How does it differentiate between the handleEvent and handleClick methods? As they both receive an event as a parameter.

Comment: It doesn't. It just wants `handleEvent`, as specified e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventListener). Your `handleClick` is explicitly called from `handleEvent`, but it could be called `eatGrassThenMoo` and accept more leafy parameters, for all the browser cares.

Comment: I see what you're saying! Thank you